# jQuery validate remote message and continue submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a quick question about the jQuery.validate.js plugin from bassistance. I'm using version 1.6 of this plugin.

The question is about the remote function. I only have to display a error when some values are not in a particular range. The form still can be submitted when these values are not in the range.

I've created the remote validation, but my form doesn't submit when the values are not in range.

My code is:

```
    rules[elm.attr('name')] = {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        remote: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkpostcode'
        }
    };
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: you have to echo 'false' from server side if value not in range

Comment: Hi Loganphp, That's allready done, but the form needs to be submitted even if the value is 'false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with injecting a custom label under the input value. Not a validation message, so the validation still continues sending the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just due to your request ajax being processed and in between your form submitted which is not yet validated.

To overcome this issue and get ride of this, just add this to your remote method:

```
remote: {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'checkpostcode',
    async: true
}
```